# How to reshape a (x, y) numpy array into a (x, y, 1) array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do you reshape a (55, 11) numpy array to a (55, 11, 1) numpy array?

Attempts:

- Simply doing `numpy_array.reshape(-1, 1)` without any loop produces a flat array that is not 3D.
- The following `for loop` produces a "cannot
  broadcast error":

```py
for i in range(len(numpy_array)):
       numpy_array[i] = numpy_array[i].reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious `x.reshape(55,11,1)`?  Or have I been using `numpy` too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for  `numpy.expand_dims`(https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)?

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.rand(55,11)
print(a.shape) # 55,11
print(numpy.expand_dims(a, 2).shape) # 55, 11, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a newaxis to the array

```py
my_array = np.arange(55*11).reshape(55,11)
my_array.shape
# (55, 11)
# add new axis
new_array = my_array[...,None]
new_array.shape
# (55, 11, 1)
```

Can specify new shape in `reshape` too:

```py
new_array = my_array.reshape(*my_array.shape, 1)
new_array.shape
# (55, 11, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers recommends using `expand_dims`.  That's a good answer, but if you look at its code, and strip off some generalities, all it is doing is:

```
In [409]: a = np.ones((2,3)); axis=(2,)
     ...: out_ndim = 2+1
     ...: shape_it = iter(a.shape)
     ...: shape = [1 if ax in axis else next(shape_it) for ax in range(out_ndim)]

In [410]: shape
Out[410]: [2, 3, 1]
```

followed by a `return a.reshape(shape)`.

In other words, the function call is just hiding the obvious,  expand a (x,y) to (x,y,1) with

```
 a.reshape(x,y,1)
```

Are you seeking some 3d 'magic' akin to the `-1` in `numpy_array.reshape(-1, 1)`?

Personally I like to use `None` to add dimensions, so prefer the other answer `[...,None]`. But functionally it's all the same.